# One HTML page not seeing CSS (except in Chrome), but on different pages it does

Tags: html, css

I made my website for a school class. It consists of 4 pages, they all work on Google Chrome.

Once I try opening them on Microsoft Edge, every page works except for the home page.

When I check the console on Microsoft Edge, it can't find the map with all 4 CSS pages on the homepage. But on other pages it does, I can't see any differences in the code.

The first page (that doesn't work on Microsoft Edge):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<title>Appels</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS4.css">
<link rel="icon" href="Fotos/Appel-jg.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<style>
  body,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif
  }
  
  .bar,
  h1,
  button {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif
  }
  
  .fa-anchor,
  .fa-coffee {
    font-size: 200px
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <div class="top">
    <div class="bar red card left-align large">
      <a class="bar-item button hide-medium hide-large right padding-large hover-white large red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      <a href="AppelSite.html" class="bar-item button padding-large white">Home</a>
      <a href="PopulaireAppels.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Populaire Appels</a>
      <a href="Recepten.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Recepten</a>
      <a href="Contact.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="bar-block white hide hide-large hide-medium large">
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="container red center" style="padding:128px 16px">
    <h1 class="margin jumbo">APPELS</h1>
    <p class="xlarge">Wouter Schuur</p>
    <p class="xlarge">18AO-A</p>
  </header>

  <!-- First Grid -->
  <div class="row-padding padding-64 container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="twothird">
        <h1>Appels</h1>
        <h5 class="padding-32">De appel is de vrucht van de plant Malus domestica. De vlezige vrucht bestaat uit drie lagen, maar soms vormen twee of drie lagen een geheel en zijn ze afzonderlijk niet meer te herkennen. Zo zijn bij de appel het exocarp en mesocarp niet meer
          van elkaar te onderscheiden en vormen gezamenlijk met de opgezwollen bloembodem het vruchtvlees. Het klokhuis is het endocarp met daarin de zaadjes (pitjes) en in het midden de vaatbundel naar het steeltje.</h5>

        <p class="text-grey">De appel (Malus domestica) is er in veel smaken, van friszuur tot zoet. Hij wordt vaak rauw genuttigd, maar hij wordt ook veel toegepast in de keuken in bijvoorbeeld appeltaart of als garnering op pannenkoeken. En hij wordt vaak verwerkt tot appelsap,
          appelcider, appelmoes en appelstroop.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="third center">
        <i class=""><img src="Fotos/Appels.png" alt="Rode appel" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second Grid -->
  <div class="row-padding light-grey padding-64 container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="twothird">
        <h1>Over deze site</h1>
        <h5 class="padding-32">Ik, Wouter Schuur, heb deze site voor school gemaakt. Ik zit op het Horizon College in Alkmaar, en dit was een opdracht tijdens de tweede periode in het eerste jaar voor het vak Frontend. Ik heb het onderwerp "Appels" gekozen omdat dat een van
          de eerste dingen was die in mij op kwam. Daarnaast is het onderwerp ook niet heel erg belangrijk, het gaat meer over hoe de site er uit ziet.
        </h5>

        <p class="text-grey">Voor deze Site heb ik een template van W3 schools gebruikt. De reden daarvoor is dat ik het zonde van de tijd die ik had vond om de hele layout van de site zelf te maken. Terwijl er hele mooie templates op het internet staan, daarnaast heb ik
          grotendeels wat er op de site te zien is zelf gemaakt. Het enige van W3 School is de template.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="third center">
        <i class=""><img src="Fotos/Horizon.png" alt="Rode appel" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container black center opacity padding-64">
    <h1 class="margin xlarge">""</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="container padding-64 center opacity">
    <div class="xlarge padding-32">

    </div>
  </footer>

  <script>
    // Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
      if (x.className.indexOf("show") == -1) {
        x.className += " show";
      } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" show", "");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Another page, that does work on every browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<title>Appels</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/CSS4.css">
<link rel="icon" href="Fotos/Appel-jg.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<style>
  body,
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif
  }
  
  .bar,
  h1,
  button {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif
  }
  
  .fa-anchor,
  .fa-coffee {
    font-size: 200px
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <div class="top">
    <div class="bar red card left-align large">
      <a class="bar-item button hide-medium hide-large right padding-large hover-white large red" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      <a href="AppelSite.html" class="bar-item button padding-large white">Home</a>
      <a href="PopulaireAppels.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Populaire Appels</a>
      <a href="Recepten.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Recepten</a>
      <a href="Contact.html" class="bar-item button hide-small padding-large hover-white">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="bar-block white hide hide-large hide-medium large">
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="bar-item button padding-large">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="container red center" style="padding:128px 16px">
    <h1 class="margin jumbo">POPULAIRE APPELS</h1>
    <p class="xlarge">Wouter Schuur</p>
    <p class="xlarge">18AO-A</p>
  </header>

  <!-- First Grid -->
  <div class="row-padding padding-64 container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="twothird">
        <h1>Elstar</h1>
        <h5 class="padding-32">De Elstar is een appel met een rode blos op een geelgroene ondergrond. Er zijn echter zeer veel kleurmutanten van helderrood tot donkerrood. In tegenstelling tot Jonagold smaken appels zonder blos ook goed. De smaak heeft een karakteristiek aroma.
          Het vruchtvlees is roomwit en sappig. Elstar kan wel in het appelgebak, maar houdt veel vocht vast. Dit kan gecompenseerd worden door middel van gedroogde vruchten. Ook is deze appel geschikt voor appelmoes of -sap.</h5>

        <p class="text-grey">In 2006 bestond 45 procent van het in Nederland aanwezige appelareaal uit Elstar. In Nederland behoort Elstar tot de door de consument hoogst gewaardeerde appelsoorten. Ook het vruchtsap en de moes worden veel verkocht.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="third center">
        <i class=""><img src="Fotos/Rode-Appel.png" alt="Rode appel" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second Grid -->
  <div class="row-padding light-grey padding-64 container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="twothird">
        <h1>Granny Smith</h1>
        <h5 class="padding-32">De granny smith is een populair appelras, afkomstig uit Australie. Dit ras werd rond 1865 door Marie Ana (Granny) Smith gekweekt. Er wordt verondersteld dat het een kruising is van de Malus sylvestris, de wilde appel, met een inheemse appelsoort.
          Spoedig werd de granny smith populair in Nieuw-Zeeland. Rond 1935 werd de soort in Engeland geintroduceerd en in de jaren 70 in de Verenigde Staten.</h5>

        <p class="text-grey">Granny smith is een groene appel. Soms hebben ze een gele of rozeachtige blos. De appel is zuur en kan worden gekookt of uit de hand worden gegeten. Ook wordt het ras voor salades gebruikt, omdat de plakjes niet zo snel bruin worden als andere
          appelrassen.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="third center">
        <i class=""><img src="Fotos/Granny-Smith.png" alt="Rode appel" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container black center opacity padding-64">
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="container padding-64 center opacity">
    <div class="xlarge padding-32">

    </div>
  </footer>

  <script>
    // Used to toggle the menu on small screens when clicking on the menu button
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("navDemo");
      if (x.className.indexOf("show") == -1) {
        x.className += " show";
      } else {
        x.className = x.className.replace(" show", "");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI: the first person in English is with a capital letter: I instead of i.

Comment: lol, thanks i guess. Was a bit sloppy with typing it all out.

Comment: Is your `index.html` in the same location as your other .html pages?

Comment: Do you get a 404 error for all of your stylesheets in the developer toolbar / do you see your stylesheets when viewing the page source?

Comment: I didn't get any 404 errors,

Comment: If by index.html you mean the home page, yes. (Kind of a noob here, sorry)

Comment: And are your stylesheets loaded into your HTML when you go to 'view page source'?

Comment: When i go to "View page source" i do not see any CSS loaded. but only when i'm checking the Source of the home page. When i check Page Source of the other pages, i do see it.

Comment: @WouterS When on your homepage, do you see any CSS being loaded in the network tab (dev tools)? Refresh the page to see everything loaded in the network tab. If not, they are not being loaded at all on your homepage.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, your browser may have an old version of the site in its storage.

Comment: Press F12 and then Network and then reload the page to see if the CSS is loading

Comment: I cleared the browser cache, when i go to "Network" i don't see anything.
But not just on the homepage, i don't see anything on the Network tab on any page.

Comment: That's not possible. If you see it in your page source, you can see it in your network tab as well. You have to refresh the page to see everything appear in your network tab.

Comment: On the home page there isn't anything on the network tab.
But now there's some random "fonts.gstatic.com" HTTPS protocol things on the other pages when i check the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is no head tag maybe that causes a problem.

I know in HTML5 it can be omitted but you can try.

Comment: I added a head tag, but it didn't solve it. I found the problem, on microsoft edge it just doesn't see the CSS. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it.

I just made a brand new file, and copied everything from the homepage to that.
Now it works perfectly, I have no idea what the problem was. My best guess is that it was using some old version of that file.

Comment: So you didn't clear your cache previously, like @Matt.Hamer5 proposed?

Comment: Don't post answer for question that doesn't reproduce an actual issue, instead vote/flag to close it.